# When will my blocking on superuser ends?

Tags: support, post-ban

For asking questions of same type again, I was blocked from asking questions in superuser for more than 10 days. Still am not able to ask questions. When will my blocking ends ? Is there any way to know it ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/question-bans ("*The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out".*") should be linked from the error message as well.

Comment: @DanielBeck i remember my question ban on MSO having expired due to a site upgrade

Answer (score 0):

If you could post answer's(I hope you don't banned for that too) then it will be good to post good answer's to contribute here, if that is also banned then try to edit the posts on SU and let the community believe on you that you are a trusted user and it will remove your ban from here. It has happened with me and  did the edit in my question posts and edited some post over here and got back my account.