# Is there any way to delete my question that has comments and answers?

Tags: discussion, questions

Some days ago I posted some repeating questions in superuser. As a result they are no longer accepting questions from me. Now I want to delete those questions. But the problem is that, those questions have comments and answers. Is there any way to delete those questions ? If not, what should I do ?

Comment: Deleting questions will not improve your situation

Comment: @OliverSalzburg So what should I do to remove my ban ?

Comment: you've been told in comments here how to remove the ban. http://meta.superuser.com/q/7800/4377 please re-read it & revisit your posts.

Comment: @Sathya How can I contribute positively to superuser ?

Comment: @TomJ read the linked answer. Specifically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/133693.

Answer (score 8):

We usually do not delete questions with upvoted answers, unless these questions are egregiously off topic or otherwise not appropriate for the site.

Also, your flags for having these questions deleted were declined with a message telling you that every deleted question makes your question ban *worse*, not better. Basically, you want  to have *no* deleted, closed questions.

Please read everything in [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/86998#86998) to see what you can do to improve your situation.

This amounts to:

- Improving your existing questions to have them upvoted or reopened
- Contributing positively to the site in the form of good answers or edits

We cannot help you any further. Moderators cannot lift the ban—only you can.